# Tailwind css not updating

Tags: css, tailwind-css

TailwindCSS was working fine and few hours later my PC got restarted. After that for my practice, I deleted written code from body. Then started coding again and then saw that Tailwind does not update the styles. What could be the reason? Does anyone have solution?

Comment: what is tailwind

Comment: How are you running Tailwind CSS? That is, how did you bootstrap your Tailwind project? Tailwind CLI? Manually configuring PostCSS? Tailwind Just-In-Time compiler? Please clarify.

Comment: Used CLI method

Comment: Got it. Can you clarify exactly where the "Tailwind" does not update? In the CSS file itself or the browser?

Comment: It doesn’t update to that css file and browser absolutely

Answer (score 1):

I was having similar issue, then I ran the Tailwind build script again:

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./index.css -o ./tailwind.css -w
```

and then it started working properly